# Jquery Filter list by child

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, listview, html-lists

I'm pretty new to Jquery'
I'm trying to filter an ordered list using child class instead of the list contents.
In this case, i need to filter by the class "title" instead of full "li" contents.
Can this be achieved with js?
Thanks.

```
<ol data-filter="true">
    <li>
    <div class="title">Andy</>
    Age:9
    Class:5
    Hobby: Sketching
    Food: Chicken
    Allergies: NONE
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: How do you define "filter"?

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML example:

```
 <ol>
     <li>
       <div class="title">Andy</div>
         Age:9
         Class:5
         Hobby: Sketching
         Food: Chicken
         Allergies: NONE
    </li>
    <li>
       <div class="title">Paul</div>
         Age:10
         Class:3
         Hobby: Sky Diving
         Food: Oranges
         Allergies: Dairy
    </li>
</ol>
```

You can use the jQuery below to select Andy:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var selectedListItem = $('#myList .title:contains("Andy")').parents("li");
    selectedListItem.hide();
});
```

Example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xgPYx/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to loop through the li elements and either remove or hide them.

```
function filterByTitle(listID, title) {
    $("#" + listID + " li").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find(".title").html() != title)
           $(this).remove(); //can use .hide() instead of .remove if desired
    });
}
```

See the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7KW66/